# iOS Close Safari page after openURL

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I need to authorize user with a custom Web Service that use OAuth2.

To do this i've made a button that redirect to Safari and show the Web Service Login.

After logged in, Web Service redirect with a custom scheme URL to my app.
All works fine but Safari Page (used for log in) is still open.

It's possible to close this Safari "card" when it is back to my App after Redirect with custom Scheme?

Comment: You could add a JavaScript close-tab function to your page, but I suspect it prompts for user interaction with an alert. You'd probably be better just to redirect to your home page.

Comment: did you try try javascript:window.close(); ?